# How to send logs to a different location : Kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, go-zap

So I want to develop multiple flavors of log one for generic use and other for performing a specific operation

I want to separate those logs by storing them in a different location and using them for further processing.

I can see the logs in Kubernetes clusters are stored in nodes - /var/log/container/*.log.
How can I store specific logs in a separate place (maybe something like /var/log/container/specificoperation/*.log.) What changes I need to do in kubernetes architecture to make this happen

Library I am using for logging: https://github.com/uber-go/zap

Comment: Why not use a local Logstash instance with different ports for each kind of log? Or setting some other metadata/tag

Comment: @RafaeldeBem: Can you quote an example ?

Comment: [Filebeat/Logstash and Zap](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/go-zap/current/setup.html) can be used together to ship your logs somewhere else, say Zabbix/Elasticsearch/Prometheus. It's a separate service that listens on a TCP port for logs. You can also use Filebeat on Kubernetes easily.

Comment: [Grafana and Loki](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/) are pretty nice, i believe you can backup logs to S3 or Dynamo if you run in AWS

Answer (score 0):

One common architecture is to install a node-level collector as a daemon set, for example [filebeat](https://github.com/elastic/beats/tree/main/filebeat), direct the collector's output to [logstash](https://github.com/elastic/logstash), then use `logstash` pipeline rules to selectively direct logs to the final destinations.

Comment: I am storing logs at a custom location(not stdout or stderr). I can see the logs inside the pods(when I ssh to the pods) rather than in the nodes. As such node-level collector won't work. Unless I am missing something

Comment: You can also configure filebeat as a sidecar container within your pod to collect from its log files.

Comment: Any example that you can suggest how to do so. I am using docker desktop to simulate kubernetes